# Python 2.7__unicode__(self) not working

Tags: python, django

**unicode**(self) is not working for me. I can still see 'Name Object' in the admin. My code is as follows:

```
import datetime # standard python datetime module
from django.db import models # Djangos time-zone-related utilities
from django.utils import timezone

class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Thanking you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you have is that you need to define the `__unicode__` method within the class definition.

```
import datetime # standard python datetime module
from django.db import models # Djangos time-zone-related utilities
from django.utils import timezone

class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

should work for you.

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh I would highly appreciate it if you could click the check mark under the vote counter to the left of my answer.  It would indicate that this question has been adequately answered and we both get extra rep!

Comment: i was trying to do it as soon as you put the answer but stack-overflow wasn't allowing me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python INDENTION will be responsible most of the time, to work correclty, use the editor or separate out the   **_*unicode*_(self)** with tab

```
      def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```